# Nutch and save crawl data to Amazon S3

Tags: solr, amazon-s3, hadoop, nutch

I am trying to evaluate if Nutch/Solr/Hadoop are the right technologies for my task.

PS: Previously I was trying to integrate Nutch (1.4) and Hadoop to see how it works.

Here is what I am trying to achieve overall, 
a) Start with a Seed URL(s) and crawl and parse/save data/links 
   --Which Nutch crawler does anyway.

b) Then be able to query the crawled indexes from a Java client
   --- (may be either using SolrJ client)

c) Since Nutch (as of 1.4.x) already uses Hadoop internally. I will just install Hadoop and configure in the nutch-**.xml

d) I would like Nutch to save the crawled indexes to Amazon S3 and also Hadoop to use S3 as file system.
   Is this even possible? or even worth it?

e) I read in one of the forums, that in Nutch 2.0, there is a data layer using GORA that can save indexes to HBase etc. I don't when 2.0 release is due. :-(
Does anyone suggest to grab 2.0 "inprogress" trunk and start using it, hoping to get a released lib sooner or later?

PS: I am still trying to figure out how/when/why/where Nutch uses Hadoop internally. I just cannot find any written documentation or tutorials..Any help on this aspect is also much appreciated.

If you are reading this line, then thank you so much for reading this post up to this point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop can use S3 as its underlying file system natively. I have had very good results with this approach when running Hadoop in EC2, either using EMR or your own / third-party Hadoop AMIs. I would not recommend using S3 as the underlying file system when using Hadoop outside of EC2, as bandwidth limitations would likely negate any performance gains Hadoop would give you. The S3 adapter for Hadoop was developed by Amazon and is part of the Hadoop core. Hadoop treats S3 just like HDFS. See http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 for more info on using Hadoop with S3.

Nutch is designed to run as a job on a Hadoop cluster (when in "deploy" mode) and therefore does not include the Hadoop jars in its distribution. Because it runs as a Hadoop job, however, it can access any underlying data store that Hadoop supports, such as HDFS or S3. When run in "local" mode, you will provide your own local Hadoop installation. Once crawling is finished in "deploy" mode, the data will be stored in the distributed file system. It is recommended that you wait for indexing to finish and then download the index to a local machine for searching, rather than searching in the DFS, for performance reasons. For more on using Nutch with Hadoop, see http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial.

Regarding HBase, I have had good experiences using it, although not for your particular use case. I can imagine that for random searches, Solr may be faster and more feature-rich than HBase, but this is debatable. HBase is probably worth a try. Until 2.0 comes out, you may want to write your own Nutch-to-HBase connector or simply stick with Solr for now.